# What will I break if I install a newer version of a library?

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, libraries

I'm currently using Ubuntu MATE 16.04.3 LTS.

I'm a *Kerbal Space Program* player, trying to use a particular game mod called *Principia* to better model multi-body and non-uniform body orbits.  The current version of *Principia* for KSP versions 1.5, 1.6, and 1.7, designated Fibonacci, requires libc++ and libc++abi -- which I have, at version 3.7.something, but this game mod requires version 6.0-2.

This version is available in Ubuntu 18.04.2; I can install it by setting up the correct repository and installing those libraries and their dependencies.  However, nothing stands alone (in Linux, as in life): what else is likely to break if a couple C++ libraries are substantially ahead of what the system expects?

I'd prefer not to upgrade my Ubuntu, because due to third part software there's not an actual reliable upgrade path; I wind up having to do a clean install and reinstall my third party and non-standard packages

Comment: fyi:  Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS is actually EOL, as only Ubuntu desktop (with Unity 7), server, Ubuntu Kylin are supported for 5 years. or as written in the release notes "*Maintenance updates are provided for 5 years for Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Cloud, Ubuntu Base, and Ubuntu Kylin. All the remaining flavours are supported for 3 years*" http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/  so consider upgrading as your desktop any many packages are EOL  Use `ubuntu-support-status` to check your security status.

Comment: Is there a snap or flatpak version? These are self-contained and can use libraries that are widely different from their hosts'.

Comment: Dagnabbit, when I installed 16.04 MATE (last time I rebuilt my hardware) I'd swear I read it was supported until 2021.  By the time you can be sure a new version is working right and has what you need, it's only got two years to run, apparently.

Comment: @xenoid Game mods are usually Windows/Mac/Linux all in one download and go inside the game install, not a separate system install.

Comment: @guiverc I think you're incorrect -- Ubuntu 16.04 shows maintenance support until 2021.  The libraries I'm asking about have nothing to do with the MATE desktop, so it'd be pretty silly to support my system another two years if I install Unity desktop...At the least, my question should still be on topic.

Comment: Only packages from the 'main' repo are supported for 5 years, ie. everything found on the Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop install ISOs are covered, but only parts of flavor ISOs.  The MATE, XFCE, etc. flavor desktops are found in 'universe' which is supported now on a per-package basis (most are EOL).  My comment was a security FYI and not an site-off-topic comment  (*your question is on-topic under this site's rules as I read them*), how much this matters to you is your choice.  As already suggested, use `ubuntu-support-status` to see your support status for your exact system.

Comment: And now someone thinks this is a bad question -- I'm supposed to just upgrade everything every time the opportunity is offered, never mind how much time I'll spend getting the new system installed and working the way I like.

Answer (score 1):

After asking in a couple other places and doing some digging based on the partial answers I got in one of them (the Kerbal Space Program forums, about the program for which an add-on prompted the question in the first place), I found a solution.

Although the required version of `libc++` and `libc++abi` isn't available from any of the Canonical repositories in a form compatible with Xenial, I was able to find a [ppa for `llvm-toolchain-8`](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/%7Eosomon/+archive/ubuntu/llvm-toolchain-8-xenial) that was backported to Ubuntu 16.04.  It doesn't completely support `clang 8` because a couple minor items had to be disabled for compatibility, but it does include `libc++-8-dev` and `libc++abi-8-dev`, the library version required by the very newest (released today) version of the *Principia* add-on for KSP.  And, because the libraries were built on Ubuntu 16.04, they are compatible with the install I already have; I've installed them, and verified both that my Ubuntu continues to run, and that *Principia* works in my KSP game.

Problem solved, at least for another year and a half.

And following up in 2023, I had to use the `llvm` package (now in the Ubuntu repository) to support this same mod in newer versions of KSP and *Principia* on Kubuntu 20.04 and still on Kubuntu 22.04.  Apparently the mod developers/maintainers are building on the very latest version of Ubuntu at any given time, and don't care if users have to keep upgrading their OS every few months.

I run into this with other software as well, and IMO it's a bad practice -- software should be built to run on the oldest supported version of supported OS; the only exception should be when basic functionality depends on libraries that don't exist in that older OS version.